# Edit Home page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, html

How do I make changes to the Home page in WordPress? When I go to the website URL (www.linkzgamez.com) it has a Home screen that I would like to make changes to, but I can't find it anywhere in WordPress. All of the other links on the Home page I can find and update/control in WP, but not the Home page which is set as the default theme. I even deleted another page in WP but it still appears on the Home screen which I can't locate to edit it. How do I find it?

Comment: Stackexchange has a special site for wordpress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the Wordpress Codex on creating / editing themes and templates:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates

In most cases the home page is controlled by the `index.php` file within a theme.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a quick look and it looks as if it is set to the default - showing the last 10 posts (even though you currently only have one post).

If you don't want to display posts on the front page you could create a new "Page" called "Home" and then go to:

Settings -> Reading -> Select "Front page displays a static page" and then select "Home" from the dropdown menu.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I don't see the Home page :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display).

If these files (home.php, index.php, front-page.php) don't exist in your theme folder; WordPress will use the ones in the default theme.